# How to get to a dict key from a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

lets say I have the following dict structure and a list of keys.

```
d = {
    'a': {
        'b': {
            'c': 'value'
        }
    }
}
keyList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

What is a pythonic way to reference the value of the c key in a dynamic way? In a static way I would say something like `d[a][b][c]` however if my keyList is dynamic and I need to reference the value at runtime is there a way to do this? the len of keyList is variable.

The main problem is i really don't know what to search. I tried things like dynamic dictionary path but couldn't get anything remotely close

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.reduce` with the input dict as the starting value and `dict.get` as the reduction function:

```
from functools import reduce

print(reduce(dict.get, keyList, d))
```

This outputs:

```
value
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/QuintessentialAntiqueMath